# Calculate daily average on a sparse data in Flux

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2, flux-influxdb

I manually enter data every ~1 month into a bucket. I'd like to calculate daily change between the entered numbers and display it on the graph. Seems all the operators are dependent on the data density, so the calculated values are no different than simple `difference()` between monthly entered values.

Is there a good way to calculate per day difference (daily change) of the entered values? Or in other words the average daily? So basically take difference of two entered values and divide it by number of days between?

[image]

This is how yellow line is calculated

```
from(bucket: "manual-data")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "meter")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "value")
  |> difference()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm... I would try to compute cumulative sum and then calculate derivative. Something like that:

```
  |> cumulativeSum(columns: ["_value"])
  |> derivative(unit: 1d, nonNegative: true, columns: ["_value"], timeColumn: "_time")
```

Comment: Yes, that works. Thank you! I had to modify the `difference()` function to `difference(initialZero: true, keepFirst: true)` so the results are included for all but first event.

Comment: Nice) I'm happy to help